# Is there any real reason to differentiate between POST and GET when handling incoming data?

Tags: architecture, post, get

Lately I've been using a wrapper PHP class that fetches GET and POST data and lets me access it using a single getter function. After years of developing web applications I've never had a single good reason to care whether an incoming var was coming from POST or GET. Not only that but I got really sick and tired of having to check both arrays for a single variable.

Today I noticed that codeigniter has one getter function for POST data and one for GET. Is there any point to this? Has anyone here ever had a reason to care where his data is coming from?

A couple of clarifications: I'm not asking about the differences between POST or GET or which one I should use to send data to a page. I'm asking about whether I should care if data is arriving to my page via GET or POST.

Answer (score 2):

It is a question of semantics - if an interface (such as REST) requires a higher level of semantics, then that's one good reason to care about the HTTP "verb".

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP standard defines different semantics for get/post operations (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html Sec 9.1.1)

In particular you can do information retrieval using data coming from a get request, but you shouldn't do anything which involves some notion of state change. One reason for this is that the user agent may prefetch pages (and doing get requests) without the user actually having clicked on a link. (Agreed that is notvery common among web browsers, but i've heard of mail clients doing that)

Answer (score 1):

You could care about the difference whether you want your data coming from a form (POST) or it being submitted through URL-parameters (GET). E.g. for security-reasons you wouldn't want to accept URL-data if you expect the user to fill out a form.

And just for the record: no need to check both arrays, in PHP the array $_REQUEST contains them both (plus COOKIE).

Comment: The security argument doesn't hold much water. Changing the method is trivial via browser addons, which makes writing the code to check it a waste of time. Realistically you wont bother checking this. It's like putting duct tape over a lock to keep people from picking it.

Comment: No: If the method changes it's a clear signal someone peeks and pokes. A web application firewall then has the chance to lock you out.

Comment: @initall: If you sanitize input and are already protecting against phishing, SQL injection and XSS, then do you really care if someone is peeking and poking? I'd rather spend my dimes on a secure architecture than on managing a firewall that can detect a GET when POST is expected, especially since a hacker capable of doing damage will have no problem crafting a POST if that's what you're expecting.

Comment: @Seth: This is perfectly ok with me; but in my security concept detection of peek&poke is also important and be it only for later analysis of what went wrong. A web firewall is part of a concept, _not_ the only part to rely on. If you invest time in all topics you mentioned, a distinction between GET and POST is really inexpensive. Please let me note: A web firewall can warn you before something happens and make you more aware smth. is going on.

Comment: @initall: Fair enough. If you're working on an app where security is a mission critical concern, then I can see how differentiating POST vs GET [and recording it for future analysis] would be important. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In cases of simple web forms, you probably don't care. But when security is at stake, you might well care about the difference: if somebody's putting a normally `hidden` input in a `GET` variable and you treat just as if it came from a `POST`, it's a potential attack vector.

In RESTful APIs, you definitely care about the difference: `POST` means a completely different thing than `GET` in this case, along with its much-neglected cousins, `PUT` and `DELETE`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simplest answer is that knowing how your data *should* be received is important for security.

Often you can interchange between the types, but take logins for example, you woule be a fool to allow logins to be processed through a GET. I would love to look at your server logs and then be able to see the GET variables in the request log.. unlocking all users passwords.

There are lots of reasons in that POST requires slightly more resources also, so you don't want to force only POST requests. Take navigation through your site. How would someone bookmark a page if they navigate through sending POST commands.

You should normally just instintctively know which is best for you.

Answer (score 1):

GET-Requests expose all the data to LOG-Files (yours and the proxies between), the Referrer and are visible to people looking at your browser.

Data via GET's are limited in length.

If you care about security: Why would you accept data sent by your forms via GET if you know your form method was POST?

Answer (score 1):

That's a matter of your project politics. Either and Both have their respective places.

If you feel open and friendly, use `$_REQUEST`. If you feel fascist, allow only what you expect. If you feel hacky, use both and differentiate, say allow to preserve semi-persistent config by encoding it in GET and encouraging to bookmark the page, while filling POST with strictly volatile stuff.

One reason why you might really, really want to disallow GET is password fields and the like. You don't want your users to (unknowingly) store their sensitive data in browser history, so don't encourage them to do so by allowing GET. OTOH, you can "GET" from a plain `<a href="">` so if you export any APIs for "anyone to use", provide either GET alone or both.