# Difference between httppost and httpget method in android?

Tags: android, json, https

Can anyone tell me difference between `Httpost` and `Httpget` `method.Httpclient` can execute POST and GET method.Please explain the difference between 1 and 2nd method

1.)`httpclient.execute(httppost)`

and the other one

2.) `httpclient.execute(httpget)`

Comment: Really, this isn't an [tag:android] question at all. You might find it useful to research the difference between GET and POST - there are *hundreds of thousands of simple explanations* via Google.

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3970555/1409082 http://stackoverflow.com/q/3477333/1409082 http://stackoverflow.com/q/4130646/1409082 http://stackoverflow.com/q/3477333/1409082 http://stackoverflow.com/q/5802343/1409082 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2296395/1409082 http://stackoverflow.com/q/504947/1409082 http://stackoverflow.com/q/4668701/1409082

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Http Get Method all the values that user sends to the server, embedded with the URL that we send as the request, where a third party can easily watch it. If I say it more technical way, by using the HTTP GET method, we are sending user details in the header part of the request not in the body.

[source](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2012/01/20/handling-http-get-method-in-android/)

Where as in Http Post method we transfer confidential data to a different location by using HTTP. The reason is the content goes inside the body, not with the header as in GET method.

[source](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/handling-http-post-method-in-android/)

You can also refer [android developers website](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html)

Answer (score 2):

The Apache HTTP Client supports all the commands that are supported by HTTP, such as GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS & HEAD.

Most well-known are GET & POST, where GET is used to fetch a resource from the URL and POST is used to store data at a URL. There are official ways in how the different methods should be used, especially when creating a REST API, but in real life most boil down to the GET and the POST.

For a full discussion of the different methods you can read RFC2616 describing the HTTP: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html