# difference btwn HttpPost & HttpGet in android

Tags: android

I am trying to learn android programming. I have a little bit knowledge of java.
I want to develop web app for android. So I am trying to learn it from various tutorials, articles, but, do not understand them properly , because of some confusion.

Currently , my question is What is the difference between HttpPost and HttpGet?
As they are used to make a web request , right?
What is HttpCilent ?

So , please can some one provide me a link of some useful tutorial for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between httppost and httpget method in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380311/difference-between-httppost-and-httpget-method-in-android) and all the related links inside.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  First, this are easy things you can find on Net if you do Google.

First You need to understanf what is GET and what is POST.

**GET** - Requests data from a specified resource. The GET method means retrieve whatever information (in the form of an entity) is identified by the Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to a data-producing process, it is the produced data which shall be returned as the entity in the response and not the source text of the process, unless that text happens to be the output of the process. Follow this [link](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html) for general and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html) for Android.

**POST** - Submits data to be processed to a specified resource. The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the resource identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line. Follow this [link](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) for genera and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) for android.

**UPDATE**
[Here is example for post and get](http://hayageek.com/android-http-post-get/)

Comment: Ok, Sandip.. I know this answer, but technically don't understand , thats y I have asked..  CAn provide me some example related t http post and http get ?

Answer (score 0):

In Http Get Method all the values that user sends to the server, embedded with the URL that we send as the request, where a third party can easily watch it. If I say it more technical way, by using the HTTP GET method, we are sending user details in the header part of the request not in the body.

[Http Get](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2012/01/20/handling-http-get-method-in-android/)

Where as in Http Post method we transfer confidential data to a different location by using HTTP. The reason is the content goes inside the body, not with the header as in GET method.

[Http Post](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/handling-http-post-method-in-android/)

You can also refer android developers website [you can go through this for more deep info](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am trying to understand from the link of example that you have posted. And again if questions will arise, I'll definitely ask you.